# Document based Obj-C (Mac) app issuing error about nsTextViewObj

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, osx-lion, osx-snow-leopard

I'm playing around with [Julius Guzy's](http://juliuspaintings.co.uk/cgi-bin/paint_css/animatedPaint/034-NSDocument-NSTextView.pl) sample code for creating a document based application that can save text files. I ran his code and it works perfectly and the app runs/save files ***(All in the latest version of Xcode. Though Guzy's sample code compiles using the 10.6 SDK)***. I'm trying to learn from it and rewrite the code. I have everything in order to compile the app but for the strangest thing in **MyDocument.m**. I am unable to run it.

```
@synthesize nsTextViewObj;
```

Xcode is giving me this error, which I don't really understand it.

> Existing ivar 'nsTextViewObj' for property 'nsTextViewObj' with 
>   assign attribute must be __unsafe_unretained

**nsTextViewObj;** is suppose to be linked to the "File Owners" in IB. I did that in the first place. It beats me why I'm getting that error. SDK conflicts maybe? **How can I fix this?**

Comment: try to remove the (assign) from 
@property (assign) IBOutlet NSTextView *nsTextViewObj; and see what happens -- I assume your'e using ARC but the original-sample isn't using ARC

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you. It compiled and I'm able to save the file. Has ARC depreciated?

Comment: No, Automatic Reference Control is the new thing and new Xcode -Projects use ARC per default. Also, see Xcode menu "Edit->Refactor" which has some commands to convert code to "modern times".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ARC requires some changes to the code. Xcode provides a tool to automatically convert non-ARC code to ARC: **Edit / Refactor / Convert to Objective-C ARC…**

The Xcode tool is a good start, still I would recommend you to read [Transitioning to ARC Release Notes](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html).

I don't know  Julius Guzy's code, but probably you should change it to something like:

```
@interface ifc_name : NSWindowController {
    NSTextView *__unsafe_unretained nsTextViewObject;
}
@property (unsafe_unretained) NSTextView *nsTextViewObject;
```

As the name implies, `unsafe_unretained` is not safe: when the object is deallocated, your reference is invalid. If you are deploying only to iOS 5 or higher, and OS-X 10.7 or higher, you can use `weak` instead. With `weak` your reference will become zero when the object is deallocated.

Comment: That worked too, thank you! I also tried (weak) with my other ARC woes and that fixed everything. One question though, are you familiar with  status menu apps? I'm trying to incorporate my document based app into a single status menu, but nothing appears in the menu bar. I set the UIAgent to YES, so it should appear...

Comment: I have developed a couple of status menu apps: have a look at the [NSStatusBar](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSStatusBar_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and [NSStatusItem](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSStatusItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSStatusItem) classes, you should find what you need.